# Bootstrap <b-form-input> component does not change when computed properties were changed

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I use bootstrap-vue form components in my project. I get data from vuex to my component with computed properties and then I have method that saving new data in the vuex store. When data in the store is updated, data in the computed properties is updated too, but in my form I see old data. 
But if I use `<input>` tag instead `<b-form-input>` component, data in the `<input>` is updated normally. How can I update data in the `<b-form-input>`?

```
<template>
<b-form @submit.prevent="saveWebintSet">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <b-form-group
                label="Bind Port"
                label-for="bind-port"
                class="required">

                <b-form-input
                id="bind-port"
                v-model="web['bind-port']"
                v-input-mask v-bind:data-inputmask-regex="regExps.bindPort.pattern"
                type="text">
            </b-form-input>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </b-form-group>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Save</button>
</b-form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            web: {
                get() {
                    return  this.$store.getters.GET_WEBINTF_SETTINGS;
                }
            },
         },
         methods: {
            saveWebintSet() {
                this.$store.dispatch('SAVE_WEBINTF_SETTINGS', this.web)
            },
        },
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are one-way and shouldn't be used as a v-model (unless you define them with explicit `get` and `set` methods):  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter.

You are probably better off using a data property (variable) for the v-model, and pre-populate it with the result of your store get, and then on submit set the store value to the data property (variable)

Comment: To be more specific (related to vuex) see the documentation of vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

Comment: Thanks @Troy,  but I just need an one-way 'cause I save data in the store with my method  ```saveWebintSet()```. And when I saved data in store, my computed properties are updated (I see this in vue devtools in Chrome) but in the form I see old data. I think that the problem with bootstrap form components  'cause when I use html-tags ```<input>``` , ```<select>``` etc,  values in the form are updated correct.

Comment: b-form-input / b-form-select are components, which work differently than native input/select.

Comment: I used the two-way computed property approach to get BootstrapVue input working with Vuex. For details, see [my post](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/technical/2020/11/06/bootstrap-vuex.html)